# check for existing values in Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
                if (dt.Rows[i]["Code"] == code)
                {

                    Label lblLang = (Label)(((e.Item as GridItem).FindControl("lblLang") as Label));
                    lblLang.Visible = true;

                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
```

I am adding a new language Fr-FR in the code above. fr-FR already exists in my DB's Language Table. I do not want to add duplicate values in my table. There should be only one fr-FR.
What am I doing wrong in the code above?

Comment: Are you using visual studio? If so, just put a breakpoint on the line ` if (dt.Rows[i]["Code"] == code)` and when it stops there ...F10 and then select `dt.Rows[i]["Code"]` and do a Shift + F9 (or add it to the Watch window)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using

```
dt.Rows[i]["Code"] .Equals(code, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Have a look at [StringComparison Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) or even [String.Compare Method (String, String, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx)

Comment: Should work as I belive `dt.Rows[i]["Code"] == code` is doing ref comparision.

Comment: But if the case is different, do you still believe it to be true?

Comment: tried ur code above..it says Member 'object.Equals(object, object)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: I want to compare strings. I want to check if fr-FR exists in the datatable or not. iF yes, label should be made visible. How do I do this ? plz help..thnx

Comment: how do I loop through the string values in that Datatable? I dont wanna compare references.

Comment: @astander, I was trying to say that your code should work as OP's code is doing ref comparison and most likely to fail even when case are same.

Answer (score 2):

Let's analyze the code a bit:

If you have two rows in the db

```
Code    Name
------------
En-en   English
De-de   German
Fr-fr   French
```

1. The code will first get the "en" row.
2. Does that equal "fr" - **No**
3. execute the else (insert another fr)
4. Get the "de"
5. Does that equal "fr" - **No**
6. execute the else (insert another fr)
   ...

as you can see, you are inserting one fr-fr row, for all the rows that precede the *real* fr row.

you should do something like this

```
bool found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  if (dt.Rows[i]["Code"] == code)
  {
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}

if (found)
{
  //show the label
}
else
{
  //add the language
}
```

basically insuring that "fr" is not present in any of the rows, before going off and inserting rows.

---

To show a label that is in a cell in a row in a grid, you need to find the cell, and *then* use FindControl to find the label, something like this (pseudocode):

```
Label lblLang = (Label)((e.Item as GridItem).Cells[0].FindControl("lblLang"))
```

The code above will most likely not work, because you'll need to tweak it to your problem, but is in the right direction.

Comment: That's another problem that cannot be solved without more information :) but at least it doesn't make five fr's, right? (I'll take a guess at the solution in an edit)